# How can I plot a satellite TLE from its orbital parameters using python and skyfield?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, two-line-elements, skyfield, poliastro, pyephem

I have a function that uses TLEs (Two-line elements) from Celestrak to plot the visibility of a satellite in Python. Is there a method with skyfield or poliastro to plot a TLE from given orbital parameters ?

Comment: What does "plot a TLE" mean? Are you interested in generating a [Two Line Element set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set) from a set of [Keplerian orbital elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_elements#Keplerian_elements)? If you add some more detail and context it will be helpful, thanks!

Comment: Please clarify: What would be the x-axis and y-axis of the graph you desire?

Comment: OP was active after comments requesting clarification were posted, but no clarification has since been forthcoming, so I'm voting to close for "needs clarification".

Comment: Hi @benben this could be an interesting question and fun to answer, but right now it's hard to tell exactly what you are asking. Can you take a moment to clarify? Thank you!  Maybe you just want to "plot a ***trajectory*** from orbital parameters" instead of from a TLE? In that case I think you can just ask now to *propagate an orbit* from its Kelperian orbital elements with some Python package. Skyfield can't do that. PyEphem probably can, and probably Poliastro can as well.

Comment: But Keplerian orbits assume a spherically symmetric Earth, and Earth is quite oblate with a J2 of roughly 1 part per thousand. This makes orbits precess fairly fast and makes Sun-synchronous orbits possible, so any accurate propagator will take an instantaneous *osculating orbital element* and immediately convert it to a *state vector* and then do a realistic numerical propagation.

Comment: You might have more luck on https://scicomp.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Hi guys ! Sorry for not having been very active lately. What I was looking for was basically some method to convert keplerian parameters directly into a TLE, but then I only had to dig a little bit into the TLE parameters to understand how to do so. This issue can probably be closed. Thanks for your concern and interest !